# Laravel nullable migration with foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have `items` table with `supplier_id` column and the foreign key to that column. The column is not nullable and I want to make it nullable. So the `up()` method works:

```
$table->integer('supplier_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();
```

But I can't get `down()` method to work, always get the error:

```
Cannot change column 'supplier_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'items_supplier_id_foreign'
```

Latest attempt:

```
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['supplier_id']);
            $table->integer('supplier_id')->unsigned()->nullable(false)->change();
            $table->foreign('supplier_id')->references('id')->on('suppliers');
        });
    }
```

Any suggestions? I'm using Laravel 5.4

Comment: By my logic, it's one thing to change a not nullable field to a nullable field, but another thing to change from nullable to non-nullable, because what would happen with the existing null values? Perhaps you need to recreate the column and drop the old one after you've copied the values over.

Answer (score 0):

@apokryfos is right. See [here](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-alter-a-column-from-null-to-not-null-in-sql-server/)

> Before any changes are made to your table, it’s important to briefly go over what data can (and cannot) be specified within an existing column that you wish to alter to NOT NULL, ensuring that no row is allowed to have a NULL value in that column.

At first, you need fill all nullable values using [seeds](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding) and then modify column. Or your can drop `supplier_id` and than using `default()` method fill all rows in the table.

Comment: I believe this person wants to make it null... `The column is not nullable and I want to make it nullable.`

Comment: @user3158900 yes, but he want get working ```down()``` method where reverse operation

Comment: Ahhh gotcha, should have been obvious.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Only dropping foreign key constraint is not enough if you're changing the column next, you have to also drop its index. Below is the migration down function

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->dropForeign('users_role_id_foreign');
   $table->dropIndex('users_role_id_foreign');
});

// Conflict with change on same Blueprint instance (strange)
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('role_id')->change();
});
```

Credits: [Github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/20823)